# generating plots inside a loop, using the pipe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to generate plots inside a loop. I need to pipe in the data argument to ggplot like so:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(5,8,9))

data %>% ggplot(aes(x=a, y=b)) +
    geom_point()
```

When generating plots from inside a loop, we need to pass ggplot to `print()`, but this doesn't seem to play well when piping in the data argument:

```
# This works
for(i in 1:2){
  (ggplot(data, aes(x=a, y=b)) +
    geom_point()) %>%
    print()
}

# This does not
for(i in 1:2){
  data %>%
  (ggplot(aes(x=a, y=b)) +
     geom_point()) %>%
    print()
}
```

Is there a way to make the pipe play nice with the parentheses around the ggplot call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including `data` in the parentheses:

```
for(i in 1:2){
  (data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=a, y=b)) +
     geom_point()) %>%
    print()
}
```